# Problem Unexpected Message : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient, http-get

I am a new programmer and I want to ask something how to solve this problem. I'm using java 6

This is a piece of my code

```java
private static DefaultHttpClient httpClientTrustingAllSSLCerts() throws 
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, getTrustingManager(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sc);
    Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
    return httpclient;
}

private static TrustManager[] getTrustingManager() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        } 
    };
    return trustAllCerts;
}
```

After that I run in weblogic server, this is what happened :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

please help me

this is the stack trace  :

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message                                                            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)                                                 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)                                                 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1806)                                        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:986)                                        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)                          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)                                   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)                                   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:570)                             at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:554)                                   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415)                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)                                                                                                                           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)                          at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)                                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)

Comment: Can you please share the complete exception stack trace?

Comment: i think i can, but not really complete. here it is

Comment: @MadhusoodanP can you help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Comment: @Olli actually i was confused about the certificates. I dont understand where i can find the certificates and i dont know about the password. can you explain it to me, please ?

Comment: btw, this error's cause bcz i didn't use the certificates stuff?

Comment: @JessieD'devil are you using https or http to hit the server? Looks like you have used http

Comment: Why are you still using Java 6, likely you're running into problems with the TLS support in Java 6. I'd recommend upgrading to at least Java 8, or even a higher version.

Comment: @MadhusoodanP i used https sir

Comment: @MarkRotteveel because my prgoram was set in java 6, if i upgrade, it will cause too many changes

Comment: @MadhusoodanP why you said looks like i have used http ? how can i know that sir ? if u can tell me, maybe there is some code that i don't change